# ffmpeg: create a video from images and sounds

Tags: image, audio, video, ffmpeg

You need to create a video from a set of pictures and sounds using ffmpeg.
Set of pictures: frame_% d.jpg
Sounds:
sound1.mp3 (from 0 ms)
sound2.mp3 (from 1000 ms)
sound3.mp3 (from 2000 ms)

I can create a video with one sound:

```
-i frame_% d.jpg -i sound1.mp3 -r 30 -s 1280x720 -preset ultrafast -crf 25 -shortest movie.mp4
```

and it works.

But I need to add some sounds at different times. How can I do that ? May be -filter_complex will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [adelay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay), [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix), and optionally a normalization filter such as [dynaudnorm](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#dynaudnorm) or [loudnorm](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#loudnorm).

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i frame_%d.jpg -i sound1.mp3 -i sound2.mp3 -i sound3.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:-2,format=yuv420p[v];[2:a]adelay=1000|1000[a2];[3:a]adelay=2000|2000[a3];[1:a][a2][a3]amix=inputs=3,dynaudnorm[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -preset ultrafast -crf 25 -shortest -movflags +faststart movie.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you. Working!